# ¿Por qué no devuelve la cadena de caracteres al main cuando desde una subrutina si imprime bien pero al main llega NULL?, utilizando memoria dinámica

Tags: c, memoria

Estoy haciendo un programa en C utilizando memoria dinámica, pero al intentar hacer una subfunción para sacar una cadena de caracteres de un archivo guardado en un diretorio, dentro de la subfunción me imprime bien la cadena, pero al volver al main la cadena ya llega sin contenido, no sé que pueda estar pasando, al ejecutal el codigo en el main me imprime "NULL" y no se cómo hacer para que la cadena de caracteres se devuelva al main con el contenido, por que se necesita para hacer otras subfunciones.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void extrae_archivo(char*,char*); 
void program_child(char*);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *buffer;
    extrae_archivo(argv[1], buffer);
    printf("\n\n %s \n\n", buffer);
    program_child(buffer);
    free(buffer); //libera memoria
}


void extrae_archivo(char *d1,char *buffer)
{
    int result_f=0, band=0;
    unsigned int tam_arch1=0;
    FILE* Arch1;
    printf("\n\nDireccion para lectura de archivo: %s\n\n", d1);

    Arch1=fopen(d1, "r+"); //Extraccion de archivo de la ruta especificada
    if(Arch1==NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\nERROR AL ABRIR EL ARCHIVO\n\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    fseek(Arch1, 0, SEEK_END);
    tam_arch1=ftell(Arch1); //Tamaño del archivo
    buffer= (char*)malloc(tam_arch1*sizeof(char)); //reserva memoria
    rewind(Arch1);
    result_f=fread(buffer, 1, tam_arch1, Arch1);
    if(result_f!= tam_arch1)
    {
        printf("\n\nERROR AL LEER EL ARCHIVO\n\n");
        band=1;
    }
    if(band==0)
    {
        printf("\n\n %s \n\n", buffer);
    }
    fclose(Arch1);
}


void program_child(char *buffer)
{
    char *args[]={"programa hijo", buffer, NULL};
    int  status=0;
    int pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
        printf("\n\n Inicio del proceso child en parent\n\n");
        int hijo = execv("./memoria2.bin", args); //ejecución del proceso hijo 
        if(hijo==-1)
            printf("\n\n Error al ejecutar \n\n");
    }
    else if(pid==-1)
        printf("\n\n Error al entrar al child \n\n");
    else 
    {
        wait(&status);
        printf("\n\n fin del proceso child  en parent\n\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es sutil pero muy común en [c](/questions/tagged/c): los cambios dentro de tu función `extrae_archivo` no se reflejan fuera de dicha función porque el puntero `buffer` que le estás pasando, se copia dentro de la función y modificas la copia. Puedes ver ese efecto con este corto código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(char *puntero)
{
    printf("El puntero %p contiene '%s' y esta en la direccion %p\n", puntero, puntero, &puntero);
}

int main()
{
    char *puntero = NULL;

    printf("El puntero %p contiene '%s' y esta en la direccion %p\n", puntero, puntero, &puntero);
    f(puntero);

    return 0;
}
```

Que [muestra la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##tY6xCsJADIbn5ilCpfYUFfeqm1txc3M5rqkNnLlyvQoiPvtZxKI@gFsS/j/fZ5bGajnHOGExtq8IN12o2K2aHcDVcYW1Mo32OG97CeTdDO6QtJ4l1CrdW3yfMWvROAlMQphnXY43pC5oJEGrsWJPxrCTIXeSdDHWvobpCCjgATD8x4tmUS/ejwFu8XAsywL@7pHU6rNA4in0XnA9CMb4BA):

> ```
> El puntero (nil) contiene '(null)' y esta en la direccion 0x7ffd9c7f8500
> El puntero (nil) contiene '(null)' y esta en la direccion 0x7ffd9c7f84d8
> ```

El primer texto corresponde al puntero que está en `main` mientras que el segundo corresponde al puntero que está en `f`, podemos ver que tienen la misma información **pero** (como se puede ver) **no son el mismo puntero** (porque tienen una dirección de memoria diferente).

Si quieres que los cambios dentro de una función se reflejen fuera de ella, debes pasar un puntero al dato que quieres modificar:

```
void extrae_archivo(char *d1,char **buffer)
//                                ^^ <--- Puntero al puntero del bufer
{
    ...

    *buffer = (char*)malloc(tam_arch1*sizeof(char)); //reserva memoria
//  ^ <--- Modificamos el buffer original, no su copia

    rewind(Arch1);
    result_f=fread(*buffer, 1, tam_arch1, Arch1);
//                 ^ <--- Usamos el buffer original, no su copia.

    ...

    if(band==0)
    {
        printf("\n\n %s \n\n", *buffer);
//                             ^ <--- Usamos el buffer original, no su copia.
    }

    ...

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *buffer;
    extrae_archivo(argv[1], &buffer);
//                          ^ <--- Enviamos la direccion del buffer, no el buffer.

    ...

    free(buffer); //libera memoria
}
```